# The second $T dS$ equation

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I know that the $T dS$ equations are obtained from systems undergoing *internally reversible processes*, and I also understand where the first one comes from.

As for the second equation, it is obtained using both the enthalpy equation and the first $T dS$ equation.

What I am having a difficult time understanding is when the differential forms

$$dH = dU + \underline{d(PV)} = dU + \underline{pdV + Vdp.}$$

The underlined terms are what's confusing me. They are to equal each other. I do not know what they are trying to express and what the quantities mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$dU = TdS - pdV$$

Then add the term what's confusing you both sides and in the end you will notice why

$$d(U+pV) = TdS - pdV + pdV + Vdp = TdS + Vdp$$

First term on the left hand side is nothing but $dH = d(U+pV)$

Comment: Thank you. What I also find confusing is when expanding $d(PV)$, what does it mean? What are they trying to express?

Comment: $pV$ is the work and you get the infinitesimal  change in work from $pdV+Vdp$ where in an isobaric case this will lead to the first term and in case of isovolumetric this will lead to second term.

Comment: +1. Ah, hence *incompressible*.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $P=x\;and\;V=y$, .
So, $PV=xy$
Now $P$ and $V$ can take any positive real values.
So $x\in\mathbb R^{+}$ and $y\in\mathbb R^{+}$.
Now take $g:\mathbb R^{+}\times\mathbb R^{+}\to\mathbb R$
s.t. $g(x,y)=xy$.
Now $dg=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\Big\rvert_y dx+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\Big\rvert_x dy \tag{1}$
We can see that
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\Big\rvert_y =\frac{\partial xy}{\partial x}\Big\rvert_y =y$.
And, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\Big\rvert_x =\frac{\partial xy}{\partial y}\Big\rvert_x = x$.

So, 1 becomes,
$dg=ydx+xdy$.

As $x=P$ and $y=V$.  So, $g=PV$.
Thus $d(PV)=VdP+PdV$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I only understood a little bit of that, I still did not understand it fully. Partial derivatives are still very new to me, if you could explain it in other words for me I would be grateful, and perhaps I could understand it at least a little better.

Comment: $d(PV)$ is the change in $PV$ when $P$ and $V$ is changed to $dP$ and $dV$ respectively. $dP$ and $dV$ are very very small. So, $d(PV)=[(P+dP)(V+dV)] - PV= (PV+PdV+VdP+dPdV)-PV=PdV+VdP+dPdV=PdV+VdP$ ($dPdV$ can be neglected). So you can see that change in $PV$ is the the sum of product of $dV$ keeping $P$ fixed and product of $dP$ keeping $P$ fixed. Naively the form of $d(PV)$ you can relate to product rule of differentiation.

Comment: Thank you, I already marked an answer to the question, but this is helpful, as well. Why do they have to be very small?

Comment: That's what the meaning of differentials.It is the very very small change in the quantity PV.

Comment: Haha, yes, you are right!